# How to recover Cassandra node from failed bootstrap

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, bootstrapping

A node when down while bootstrapping a new node, and the bootstrapping failed. The node shut down, leaving the following messages in its log:

```
INFO  [main] 2015-02-07 06:03:32,761 StorageService.java:1025 - JOINING: Starting to bootstrap...
ERROR [main] 2015-02-07 06:03:32,799 CassandraDaemon.java:465 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/10.0.3.56).  If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
```

How do I recover the situation? Can I restart the bootstrap process once the failed node is back online? Or do I need to revert the partial bootstrap and try again somehow?

I have tracked down the original cause. The new node was able to connect to the node at 10.0.3.56, but 10.0.3.56 was not able to open connections back to the new node. 10.0.3.56 contained the only copy of some data that needed to be moved to the new node (replication factor == 1), but its attempts to send the data were blocked.

Comment: Are you trying to replace a dead node?

Comment: No, this was adding a new node. One of the existing keyspaces used a replication factor of 1, and one of the nodes containing the only copy of data that need to be moved to the new node was not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this involves data move, not just replication, and based on the place in the code where exception is thrown, I assume you are trying to replace a dead node as it is described here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_replace_node_t.html

By the look of it, the node did not get to joining the ring. You can certainly doublecheck by running `nodetool status`, if the node has joined at all.

If not then you can simply delete all from the data, commitlog and saved_caches, and restart the process. What was wrong with that 10.0.2.56 node?

If this node has joined the ring then it should be still safe to simply restart it once you start node 10.0.2.56 up.

Comment: This is a new node being added to the cluster. The system keyspace was purged from disk and the service started pointed at a live and contactable seed.

Comment: Looking a little closer at my logs, I don't think the .56 node was ever contactable (or if it was to start with, the firewall cutoff access during the process).

Comment: The node did manage to join the ring. 'nodetool status' from the seed showed it as UN and containing its part of the system_auth keyspace, and I can see that data on disk.

Comment: In this case you may simply restart the node.

Comment: I experience this problem when I spin up a brand new cassandra ring.  Some nodes may not join the ring and throw this error.  Yes, I can restart the service and it will work, but is there any workaround to this behaviour?